# Analyzing a function that represents the power a of a light bulb depending on distance

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to create a $g(x,y)$ function based on this given : the power of light from a light bulb of distance $d$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{d^2}$.

Now my light bulb is installed at the point $(0,0,2)$ in a plane ,and i want to create a function that represents the power of light at every point $(x,y)$.
So i thought my function should be $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{(||(x,y,0)-(0,0,2)||)^2}$ since i want the distance calculated from the $(0,0,2)$ point.

Is this correct?

Comment: In a word, yes, although you can simplify the denominator a bit.

Comment: Thank you now just another similar thought if i had 2 light bulbs one is installed at the point $(a,0,2)$ and one is at $(-a,0,2)$ for some positive constant $a$, then if let $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{||(x,y,0)-(a,0,2)||^2} +\frac{1}{||(x,y,0)-(-a,0,2)||^2}$ then this function will represent the power of light from both light bulbs for every $(x,y)$ point ?

Comment: And i'm having trouble analyzing the contour lines of that $g(x,y)$ function

Comment: If the total power of two light sources is additive, then sure. As for the contour lines, you should ask a separate question about that.